# String comparison in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, comparison

What is the difference (in bref) between (.NET)

```
myString == otherString
```

and

```
myString.CompareTo(otherString) == 0
```

Comment: Well, first statement is assignment, not comparison...

Comment: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/StringComparison.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the `==`... :/

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference, except when myString is `null`, in which case `myString.CompareTo(otherString)` throws an error (`NullReferenceException`). Also, using `CompareTo` is a little bit slower than `==`.

Only use `CompareTo` when you are interested in knowing if a string is before or after another one in an alphabetical sorting of them. For example `"Car".CompareTo("Cat")` returns -1 because "Car" is before "Cat" when ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I'd prefer using Sort with parameters in the alphabetical comparison case... (case sensitive, etc)

Answer (score 2):

`CompareTo` should *only* be used for assessing ordering. It may be that, for whatever reason, two strings compare the same for ordering purposes, but should not be considered equal (that is, `==` and `Equals` may return `false`).

To quote the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto.aspx):

> Compares this instance with a specified object or String and returns an integer that indicates whether this instance precedes, follows, or **appears in the same position** in the sort order as the specified object or String.

Emphasis added - note that it does *not* say that the two objects are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant

```
myString == otherString
```

there is no visible difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant == and not =

CompareTo implements the IComparable interface.  It returns an integer.

Comment: I know it returns an integer, because compare to "0" )

Comment: Right and == returns a boolean...that is a difference (what your were asking).

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx):

> The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or
>   alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary
>   purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are
>   equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the
>   Equals method.

The `Equals` method is more appropriate.  From [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals), the difference between `Equals` and `==` is that `Equals` requires its parameter to be non-null and `==` does not.  Plus, `==` is implemented to use `Equals` so `Equals` will always have better performance.

Comment: I didn't compare Equals with `==`, but i believe the compiler optimize both so I don't believe the Equals and "==" are different in performance. If A() uses B() and only B() I suppose both should have the same performance, but just using A() you-ll lose some milliseconds in compilation.

Comment: I know you didn't compare `Equals` with anything.  I put it in there for reference purposes, since the title of your question is "String Comparison in .Net".  `CompareTo` and `==` don't have the same purpose so comparing `CompareTo` and `==` really should just consist of noting that they are intended for different things.  As far as performance goes you will have to see what I referenced in the link.  `Equals` calls `==` but that is not all it calls, thus it has worse performance.

Comment: String.Equals also allows for passing in the StringComparison method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) which can be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The myString.CompareTo(otherString) method main purpose is to be used with sorting or alphabetizing
operations. It should not be used when the main purpose is to check the equality of strings.

To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the Equals method."

It's better to use .Equals instead of .CompareTo when looking solely for equality. since I also think it is faster for the compiler than the == operation.